# countable or uncountable set of functions

Tags: functions

I was working through some first year past papers(maths exams) and i found these two questions. I think the first statement is true and the second statement is false, but i do not really now how to formalize this in any way.

Let S = {0, 1}. The set of functions f : S → N is countable.
xix Let S = {0, 1}. The set of functions f : N → S is countable

Any ideas?thanks.

Comment: The second is definitely false. You can think of it as the set of all infinite sequences with only $0$s and $1$s, and if you add a decimal(?) point at the start, it's like it's all real numbers between $0$ and $1$ written in binary, which is uncountable. (There's some work to do to formalize that, though, since some numbers have multiple representations.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your right, the first set is countable, it is essentially $\mathbb N ^{|S|}$.  My favorite injection from this set to $\mathbb N$ is the one that sends $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{|S|})$ to the number $2^{a_1}3^{a_2}5^{a_3}\dots p_{|S|}^{a_{|S|}}$

The second set is $|S|^\mathbb N$ and is not countable. You can show that $2^\mathbb N$ is not countable by using Cantor's theorem for example, or bijecting it with the real numbers via binary representation.